# How to force sequential statement execution in Node?

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node, so please forgive me if my question is too simple. I fully appreciate the Async paradigm and why it is useful in single threads.  But some logical operations are synchronous by nature.

I have found many posts about the async/sync issue, and have been reading for whole two days about callbacks, promises, async/await etc...

But still I cannot figure what should be straight forward and simple thing to do. Am I missing something!

Basically for the code below:

```
const        fs = require('fs');
var   readline  = require('readline');


function getfile (aprodfile) {

   var prodlines = [];

   var  prodfile = readline.createInterface({input: fs.createReadStream(aprodfile)});

   prodfile.on('line', (line) => {prodlines.push(line)});
   prodfile.on('close', () => console.log('Loaded '+prodlines.length));

  // the above block is repeated several times to read several other
  // files, but are omitted here for simplicity

   console.log(prodlines.length);

   // then 200+ lines that assume prodlines already filled
};
```

the output I get is:

```
0
Loaded 11167
```

whereas the output I expect is:

```
Loaded 11167
11167
```

This is because the `console.log` statement executes before the `prodfile.on` events are completed.

Is there a nice clean way to tell Node to execute commands sequentially, even if blocking? or better still to tell `console.log` (and the 200+ lines of code following it) to wait until `prodlines` is fully populated?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the execution order of what you wrote :

```
prodfile.on('line', line => { // (1) subscribing to the 'line' event
    prodlines.push(line) // (4), whenever the 'line' event is triggered
});

prodfile.on('close', () => { // (2) subscribing to the 'close' event
    console.log('Loaded '+prodlines.length) // (5), whenever the 'close' event is triggered
});


console.log(prodlines.length); // (3) --> so it logs 0, nothing has happened yet
```

What you can do is this :

```
function getfile (aprodfile) {

   var prodlines = [];

   var  prodfile = readline.createInterface({input: fs.createReadStream(aprodfile)});

   prodfile.on('line', line => { prodlines.push(line) });
   prodfile.on('close', () => { 
        console.log('Loaded '+prodlines.length)
        finishedFetching( prodlines );
   });
};


function finishedFetching( prodlines ) {
     console.log(prodlines.length) // 200!
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jeremy.  This works fine.  Just a clarification for my education: My actual code involves opening ten files.  They are sort of config files and the app actually has to wait until all files are loaded before it can proceed into asynchronous mode.  According to your  solution, I have to create ten functions, one function for each file read, and then chain each function on the back of the other.  The main code in  'finishedFetching' will be nested ten times!  Is this correct?  Is there a better way of doing this?  Many thanks again for your help.

Comment: In that case, it's a bit more complex. You can use `Promise.all()`, or `await` 10 times. Look up `async/await`